# ec2 instance with role AmazonEC2RoleforSSM is unable to do EC2 operations in ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have an instance with AmazonEC2RoleforSSM role. I want to run ansible task in this machine which commissions ec2 instances, without setting AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.

This doesn't work as expected, it always needs to set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For anyone, like me, who's looking at this because they're trying to run Ansible playbooks with SSM, check out https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/keeping-ansible-effortless-with-aws-systems-manager/ because AWS now offers a new SSM document called AWS-ApplyAnsiblePlaybooks

Answer (score 3):

Jaks, could you explain a little bit more about what you're trying to do?

Having an instance profile with the AmazonEC2RoleforSSM policy will allow the instance to call the Systems Manager APIs and be treated as a managed instance, allowing you to use features like Run Command, Inventory, Patch Manager and the like. It will not, however, grant the instance permission to call EC2 APIs (e.g. run-instances).

What is the specific operation you're performing that's failing and what error message are you getting?

Comment: I want to create, start, stop EC2 instances via Ansible. I thought I can do this SSM role. Is it possible?

Comment: If you are trying to stop an instance, you need permissions to call the stop-instances API. The AmazonEC2RoleforSSM policy does not give you that permission (because SSM doesn't need to perform that action). If you are using Run Command to send a command to have Ansible stop an instance, the instance profile must grant permissions to stop-instances API. You can accomplish that by adding those APIs in a custom policy to the role you're using for the instance profile.

Comment: Thanks. I think, what I am trying to do is not possible with SSM

Answer (score 1):

AWS Systems Manager requires the SSM Role to be attached in order to execute a SSM Agent in the EC2 instance. [Once SSM agent was installed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-agent.html) into a particular EC2 instance, you could freely exec commands from AWS Systems Manager.

I guess after the installation of SSM agent, you can execute ansible script freely (it's not related with access key issue). Is that OK ?

Documents to execute commands with SSM:

- [Executing Commands Using Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/run-command.html)
- [Executing Commands from the Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/rc-console.html)

Comment: I have verified that SSM agent is already running. $ sudo status amazon-ssm-agent  gives amazon-ssm-agent start/running, process 2233. Do I need to do any configuration?

Comment: @jaks No. After installed SSM agent, you could see instances from SYSTEMS MANAGER SERVICES from AWS management console. Then, you can execute any commands from "Run a command" section.